# inner join root of tree to table

Tags: database, sqlite, tree, inner-join

So, I basically have two tables.

```
|   id   | marketGroupID |
|--------|---------------|
|   1    |      134      |
|   2    |      868      |
|   3    |      387      |
```

second table:

```
| marketGroupid | parentGroupID |
|---------------|---------------|
|   134         |      5987     |
|   5987        |      NULL     |
|   868         |      8796     |
|   8796        |      387      |
|   387         |      NULL     |
```

The end result should look like this:

```
|   id   | marketGroupID | parentGroupID |
|--------|---------------|---------------|
|   1    |      134      |     5987      |
|   2    |      868      |     387       |
|   3    |      387      |     387       |
```

Now I know how to INNER JOIN the both tables via

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.marketGroupID,table2.parentGroupID FROM 'table1' INNER JOIN 'table2' ON table1.marketGroupID=table2.marketGroupID;
```

Now the problem here is that this would only show the immediate parent. But I want the root parent. I don't know how many nodes will be in between the root parent and the child. All I know is, that the root parent is reached once parentGroupID is NULL. The root parent might already be the marketGroupID as is the case with id=3 or there might be 3 nodes in between as with id=2.

The point here is that I do not want the intermediate steps. The first answer in the "Duplicate" does exactly that. Furthermore does it assume a maximum number of intermediate steps. For each step there is another left join. I also don't know on which level the root parent will end up, since I don't know how many intermediate steps I have. So I would have to traverse each row from left to right until I meet null and that the last value before that.

The answers that use cte's assume, just one table. But I have too tables.
And I still only want the root parent, nothing in between.

Technically I don't even need the original market group id. For each id in table one I just need the root parentgroupid and that is it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case for using a [recursive CTE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

Start with one that generates a set of rows for each id in the first table that iterates through all the parent chains:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents(id, child, parent) AS
  (SELECT id, NULL, marketGroupID FROM table1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT p.id, p.parent, t2.parentGroupID
   FROM table2 AS t2
   JOIN parents AS p ON p.parent = t2.marketGroupID)
SELECT * FROM parents;
id          child       parent
----------  ----------  ----------
1                       134
2                       868
3                       387
1           134         5987
2           868         8796
3           387
1           5987
2           8796        387
2           387
```

In these results, the rows with a null child column are the base group ids, the rows with values in both columns are intermediates in the chain of links to the root, and the rows with a null parent column have the final root groupid for each row of `table1`. It's this last set of rows we're interested in. Adding in tracking the original child groups and filtering out the non-root rows gives the final results:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents(id, market, child, parent) AS
  (SELECT id, marketGroupID, NULL, marketGroupID FROM table1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT p.id, p.market, p.parent, t2.parentGroupID
   FROM table2 AS t2
   JOIN parents AS p ON p.parent = t2.marketGroupID)
SELECT id, market AS marketGroupID, child AS parentGroupID
FROM parents
WHERE parent IS NULL
ORDER BY id;
id          marketGroupId  parentGroupID
----------  -------------  -------------
1           134            5987
2           868            387
3           387            387
```

---

> Technically I don't even need the original market group id. For each id in table one I just need the root parentgroupid and that is it.

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents(id, child, parent) AS
  (SELECT id, NULL, marketGroupID FROM table1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT p.id, p.parent, t2.parentGroupID
   FROM table2 AS t2
   JOIN parents AS p ON p.parent = t2.marketGroupID)
SELECT id, child AS parentGroupID FROM parents WHERE parent IS NULL ORDER BY ID;
```